# Overloading Operators with char c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, operator-overloading

I am working on a homework for class on overloading operators. The problem I am having is with a char.

```
RetailItem &RetailItem::operator=(const RetailItem &objRetail) {    
    this->description = objRetail.getDescription();
    this->unitsOnHand = objRetail.getUnitsOnHand();
    this->price = objRetail.getPrice();
    return *this;
}
```

I am getting a message on Visual Studio:

> a value of type `const char *` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `char *`.

I have done some research and not found anything. If anyone can help, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I will add the `getDescription` function to provide more information. Also the description is a `*char`.

```
const char *RetailItem::getDescription() const{

    return description;
}
```

Comment: Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you really need a non-const char* member?

Comment: Incidentally, the code does not need any of those `this->`s; that's implied in member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason might be mismatch between data type of "member variables" which you used in the class and the return values of the function.

```
const char *RetailItem::getDescription() const{

    return description;
}
```

Remove const before function , keep it char *RetailItem::getDescription() const only .It should work

Comment: Although this might compile, it's most likely a bad idea (but we can't say for sure without seeing more of OP's code)

Answer (score 3):

*Probably* `RetailItem::description` is `char*` and `RetailItem::getDescription` casts this `char*` to `const char*` and returns that. You *can* add `const` qualifiers implicitly, but you *cannot* remove them the same way in the assignment:

```
this->description = objRetail.getDescription();
```

**And you *probably* shouldn't**. This will make two `RetailItem`s referring to the same resource without managing its lifetime properly, as well as not freeing the memory held previously (if it is indeed a pointer to a dynamically allocated array).

**This boils down to:** you should prefer using `std::string` over arrays.

Comment: But then I can't use the this-> with strcpy_s

Comment: Agreed, what you're doing looks very dangerous.  objRetail surely returns const char*, and specifically to stop you from doing what you're trying to do.  Re: strcpy_s: don't use strcpy_s.  Seriously, stop using char*s at all whever you can. You're using C++, not C, you don't generally have to mess with bare pointers, and should avoid them wherever possible.

Comment: I don't like using char, but as I stated it is a homework. The professor wanted a char.